# Update ASP.NET Partial View With Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update a partial view in ASP.NET MVC with an ajax form contained within the partial view. However whenever the form is submitted the entire page changes to the partial view, not just the part of the page where the partial view is contained.

My partial View Form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Archive", "Products", new { id = note.ID }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,UpdateTargetId = @*Unique ID*@ }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="Archive" class="btn btn-default"/>
}
```

The Function It Calls:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Archive(int ID)
{

    ProductNote model = db.ProductNotes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);

    model.Archived = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
    Product modelP = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(z => (z.ProductNotes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == model.ID).NoteText != null));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(modelP.ID.ToString() + "Test Test 123");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test\n\n\n");
    return PartialView("_ProductNotes", modelP);

}
```

Comment: Have you implemented all jquery refrences needed to excecute that? I mean the jquery.ajax.unobtrusive file in your Main View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to put your Patialview inside a div tag with an id

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<div id="replace-this">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Archive", "Products", new { id = note.ID }, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,UpdateTargetId = "replace-this" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="Archive" class="btn btn-default"/>
}
</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried this while debugging, doesn't have any affect on the outcome

Comment: Did you have "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" script in your view. Also, are there any element that have the same id like your target?

Comment: Yes and no, all id's are the same and the script is included in the view

Comment: I installed Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax in from Nuget Package. Then I added <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>  to my page. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the following jquery libraries at the bottom of your partial view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```